# Sleeping thread after publishing a message into a topic

Tags: ros, thread, rosbridge, turtlesim, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've been using *rosbridge* and *jroslib* as an API to it. Testing the *jroslib* with the *turtlesim*, to publish messages I'm finding some errors. I have to use *Thread.sleep(500)* to the thread sleep so the message can somehow be published into the topic, otherwise the message would not be published nor the turtle would move.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Ros ros = new Ros("localhost");
    final int[] answer = {0};
    ros.connect();

    Topic turtlePub = new Topic(ros,"/turtle1/cmd_vel", "geometry_msgs/Twist", 3);
    turtlePub.advertise();
    turtlePub.subscribe(new TopicCallback() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    });
    Message toSend = new Twist(new Vector3(2.0,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,1.8));

    turtlePub.publish(toSend);

    Thread.sleep(500);

    ros.disconnect();
    System.out.println("finished");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203837/sleeping-thread-after-publishing-a-message-into-a-topic/) by [pnakibar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21728/pnakibar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not completely familiar with jroslib, but in general ROS communications are asyncronous and run in multiple threads. If you publish a message then immediately terminate the process, the message may have enough time in the other thread which actually does the transmission, with acknowledgement and retry logic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-26**:
PS can you link to documentation for jroslib?

**Comment by [pnakibar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21728/pnakibar/) on 2015-02-26**:
It probably is exactly this!
The documentation is pretty lacking, although the API is very straightforward.
Their git: https://github.com/WPI-RAIL/jrosbridge